How can I load symbolic information in Codeview 3.14 from an .exe built with MASM32, ml.exe and link16.exe?
I cannot use ml.exe (MASM32) to directly build an 8086 .asm source. But I was successful doing it separately: first ml /Zi /c ... and then link16 /codeview .obj,,,, (this is the linker for 16 bit. "Normal" MASM32 (32 bit) linker link does not work). 
The thing is that I want to debug the .exe with Codeview 3.14, but I am still getting: "Warning: no symbolic information for ...". How could I get over this?
The .obj grew a lot with /Zi so things were added, but link16 (without /codeview) is like it truncates it back to regular .exe (identical size like even the /Zi option was not used). The /codeview linker option grows the .exe, but still no desired symbolic check ok inside Codeview application.
ml /c /Zi EX4_2_Zi.asm
link16 /codeview EX4_2_Zi.obj,,,,
When I go for: cv EX4_2_Zi.exe
Codeview loads perfectly but still:
CV0101 Warning : No symbolic information for C:\AOA\CHO4\EX4_2_Zi.exe
(Environment Windows XP Virtual Machine).

Is there anyway you can get MASM 6.11, which is a 16 bit assembler and tool set?

@rcgldr Awesome. Reached > Downloaded > Installed > Post problem, solved. WOW. Incredible. OMG. TVM!
